# How to enable CkEditor for "Global: Custom text" in views fields?

Tags: views, 8, entities, wysiwyg

How can i easily enable CKEditor for "Global: Custom text" fields in views - Drupal 8? CKEditor is only visible in a global text fields in HEADER or FOOTER. I need to change text input format in "views fields" also, but there i see only "You May include HTML or Twig" description.

Thank you!